# Advanced SELECT query

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Here's an example of my table:

Skill | SkillLevel

1 | 1

1 | 2

1 | 3

2 | 1

2 | 2

3 | 1

3 | 2

3 | 3

3 | 4

So, I want to write a query which returns me Skill 1 SkillLevel 3, Skill 2 SkillLevel 2 and Skill 3 SkillLevel 4 - Moreover, a select query to select one row of each Skill, but the one with the highest SkillLevel. All in one query, I'm clueless.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The table contains about 200 different Skills.

Comment: A simple max and group by will solve this,isn't it ?Please google first.

Comment: What a tease, I came expecting a request for an "Advanced SELECT query" and it's this...

Answer (score 3):

```
select Skill, max(SkillLevel)
from table_name
group by Skill
```

Put all of the skills into groups. Then take the max from each group. Put the correct table name where I have "table_name". This returns pairs made of:

1. a Skill
2. and the max Skill Level for that skill.

Comment: Damn it! I love these simple answers to pimp my score. All answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Skill, Max(SkillLevel)
from Skills
group by Skill
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `Skill`, MAX(SkillLevel) FROM `Skills` GROUP BY `Skill`;